# Iphone: change orientation manually

Tags: iphone

How to call shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation manually?

Content of this function has on/off flag, so when I change this flag, I need to rotate screen.

Example:

1. Disable flag
2. Tilt phone in horizontal position. shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation called and returns false
3. Enable flag: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation must be called. How to call it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are targeting iOS 5, you can call

`[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation]`

which will call `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` with the device's current orientation and will rotate the interface if that method returns `YES`.

Comment: Thank you, but I need iOS 3 support. Any other ideas how to implement it?

Comment: I WAS SEARCHING FOR THIS FOR LIKE 10 YEARS! THX, THX, THX!